# Let's Encrypt - Apache - OCSP stapling

Tags: ssl, apache-virtualhost, letsencrypt

I would like to enable [OCSP stapling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling) in my Apache server. I'm using:

- Server: Apache/2.4.7 on Ubuntu
- Certificate: [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

To the file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

I added:

> ```
> SSLUseStapling on
> ```

Then, I edited:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
```

adding this line:

> ```
> SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/tmp/stapling_cache(128000)
> ```

[I read that this would be sufficient to enable OCSP stapling](https://itigloo.com/security/how-to-configure-ocsp-stapling-on-apache-http-server/).

I checked the syntax with:

```
sudo apachectl -t
```

and it was OK.

However, upon reloading, Apache can't start.

**EDIT1:**

[Following this guide](https://sslmate.com/blog/post/ocsp_stapling_in_apache_and_nginx).

Inside my SSL virtual host file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

I added these lines below my sets of `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile`:

> ```
> SSLUseStapling on
> SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
> SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
> ```

I then edited this file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
```

adding this line:

> ```
> SSLStaplingCache shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_stapling_cache(128000)
> ```

I can now restart Apache without problems, however, OCSP does not seem to be working, based upon:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -servername www.example.com -status < /dev/null
```

> ```
> OCSP response: no response sent
> ```

What am I doing wrong, is it something related to my Let's Encrypt certificate?

Comment: On your config, I expect it's using an anonymous mapping, so the file name doesn't actually matter. The error says its run out of memory—is it possible you have some resource limit set that's keeping it from grabbing shared memory?

Comment: @derobert please check my update

Comment: That looks like it should work—I have a similar config running and it works (though my staping setup is server-wide, not just one vhost). I'd suggest changing `LogLevel` to see if you can get the reason it failed out of Apache. The only obvious one I can think of is if you have a firewall restricting outgoing traffic—it needs to let the OCSP request through.

Comment: @derobert I confirm, on my Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS EC2 doesn't work `OCSP response: no response sent`

Comment: Did you try changing the LogLevel to see if you can get an error message out of Apache?

Comment: @derobert my apache2 LogLevel is set to warn...is it not enough, should I use debug?

Comment: There are a few [log levels between warn and debug](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel). I'd try `info` first.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this a while ago myself, but I seem to have fixed it.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect berb.ec:443 -servername berb.ec -status < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep "OCSP Response Status"
OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
```

<strike>SSLLabs agrees: 97.5% (I have to enable a cipher for my LG phone)</strike>

*edit*: [SSLLabs agrees: 100%](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=berb.ec) Got 100% fixed. Stupid phone and curve support.

In my situation, I was using the common line:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/berb.ec/cert.pem
```

I changed to the fullchain.pem file and all is good.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/berb.ec/fullchain.pem
```

Alternatively, you can add a line to your VirtualHost file

```
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/berb.ec/chain.pem
```

This is my full `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ssl.conf` file. The only SSL items in the VirtualHost file are the `SSLEngine`, `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`.

```
SSLProtocol             -all +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd       DHParameters    "/etc/apache2/dhparam4096.pem"
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd       ECDHParameters secp384r1
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd       Curves          secp521r1:secp384r1
SSLUseStapling          On
SSLStaplingCache        "shmcb:/logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
SSLCompression off
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
```

<strike>I'm still working on OCSP Must Staple</strike>

**EDIT1:** Got [OCSP Must Staple](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7633) working. It's an option in the certbot client:

```
certbot --must-staple --rsa-key-size 4096
```

Answer (score 0):

For answering your question, I am copying and pasting some of the `apache2.conf` settings of my Apache server, which provides grade A encryption on my page with Let's Encrypt SSL certificates:

```
#Required modules
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module           /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so

#SSL settings
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!RC4
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 32
SSLSessionCache shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 86400
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ocsp(128000)
SSLUseStapling on
```

Additionally you may see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/114448/71087) for strengthening the `SSLCipherSuite`.